# Facebook Game Request do not appear as Notifications on iOS or Android Devices

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, kotlin

I am working on a mobile app that supposed to be on iOS and Android.
As Login mechanism I use Facebook SDK and to challenge and invite friends, I implemented the generic Game Request from the SDK.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests

Unfortunately I never recieve the notifications on the test accounts even FacebookCallback returns me the success block.

```
    requestDialog!!.registerCallback(callbackManager,
            object : FacebookCallback<GameRequestDialog.Result> {
                override fun onSuccess(result: GameRequestDialog.Result) {
                    val participants = result.requestRecipients
                    val id = result.requestId
                }

                override fun onCancel() {}
                override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {}
            }
    )
```

Anyone achived to send/receive notifications for mobile apps (not for facebook web  app)?